# Silverlight Dependancy Property Change Event Problem

Tags: silverlight, custom-controls, dependency-properties

I have a custom control that has a Dependancy Property...it has a few but let us say Dragable is my problem. The property is a boolean and I want to execute a piece of code each time it changes...a toggle.

I have two options, both shown below

```
[Category("Modal Options")]
    public bool Dragable
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(DragableProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DragableProperty, value); toggleDragable(); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Dragable.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DragableProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Dragable", typeof(bool), 
        typeof(PlussWindow), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    private void MakeDragable()
    {
        this.dragBehavior.Attach(this.LayoutRoot);
    }

    private void MakeUnDragable()
    {
        this.dragBehavior.Detach();
    }

    public virtual void toggleDragable()
    {
        if (this.Dragable)
        {
            MakeUnDragable();
        }
        else
        {
            MakeDragable();
        }
    }
```

or

```
[Category("Modal Options")]
    public bool Dragable
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(DragableProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DragableProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Dragable.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DragableProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Dragable", typeof(bool), 
        typeof(PlussWindow), new PropertyMetadata(false, (o, e) => { (o as PlussWindow).toggleDragable(); } 
         ));

    private void MakeDragable()
    {
        this.dragBehavior.Attach(this.LayoutRoot);
    }

    private void MakeUnDragable()
    {
        this.dragBehavior.Detach();
    }

    public virtual void toggleDragable()
    {
        if (this.Dragable)
        {
            MakeUnDragable();
        }
        else
        {
            MakeDragable();
        }
    }
```

Each method results in a 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'

I usually use binding to get over this problem, e.g Visibility or Text are easily done, but for custom functionality I need to enable this in code.

How do I do this, noting that the propertychanged method is static?

Comment: I place the code either in the setter or use the PropertyMetaData override which allows you to specify an handler for the changed event.

Comment: Where do you get this exception? BTW ignore you first example the second code sample is the correct approach

Comment: Have you considered calling `toggleDragable` from external code?  Looking at it I don't think this is a Dependency property issue, it looks more likely you have a fault with the way you are using this dragBehavior thing.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
public bool Dragable
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(DragableProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DragableProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DragableProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Dragable", typeof(bool), typeof(PlussWindow), new PropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(onDragableChange)));

    private static void onDragableChange(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        bool validate = (bool)e.NewValue;
        PlussWindow win = (PlussWindow) d;

        if (validate)
        {
            win.dragBehavior.Attach(this.LayoutRoot);
        }

        else
        {
            win.dragBehavior.Detach();
        }


    }
```